# A better way to invoke a group of property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, invoke

I have a wpf c# application.

I will have a function like so:

```
private void ReSetScreen()
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            ucCustomerNew.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            ucCustomerResults.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;             
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        ucCustomerNew.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        ucCustomerResults.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;           
    }
}
```

This code is basically saying check if 'invoke' is needed (because on a different thread) and if so use the appropriate way to hide 2 user controls I have created.

I have many such code segments throughout my app.

I could refactor the above as:

```
private void ReSetScreen()
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            DoMystuff()            
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        DoMystuff()
    }
}

void DoMystuff()
{
    ucCustomerNew.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    ucCustomerResults.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;      
}
```

and then if I did this for everywhere I would need to I would have to basically create 'shadow' functions.

is there a better design pattern that I could use at all?

ADDITIONAL:
Code example with extension (which gives the error of:

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'method' of 'InvokeOnMainThread(Control, Action)'

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void ReSetScreen()
    {
        WorkingClasses.Shared.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>  { ucCustomerNew.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; ucCustomerResults.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; });
    }

public  static class Shared
{
    public static void InvokeOnMainThread(this Control control, Action method)
    {
        //if (method == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
        if (!control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(method);
            return;
        }

        method();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a single helper method that takes an `Action` as argument. As far as patterns go, that would be called a 'higher-order function'.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet re: action as argument -  i think I know what you mean.  Would you have a code example to post for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class ControExtensions
  {
    public static void InvokeOnMainThread(this Control control, Action method)
    {
      if (method == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
      if (!control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(method);
        return;
      }

      method();
    }
  }
```

Place that extension in WPF utilities project, so you will be able to reuse it.
And using it is very simple:

```
this.InvokeOnMainThread(this.DoMyStuff);
```

Comment: thanks for this answer.  I am not sure which one I prefer now. I will play around with it. Thanks

Comment: That should work: InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
      {
       ucCustomerNew.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        ucCustomerResults.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
      } );

Comment: If ResetScreen is not placed in class that is inherited from control the code should look like this: ucCustomerNew.InvokeOnUiThread(()=>{ ucCustomerNew.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;});

Comment: That works, I use it in many projects, what is the base class of ResetScreen method owner?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99210/discussion-between-radin-gospodinov-and-andrew-simpson).

Comment: Hi again. there is a flaw with this.  I cannot seem to step through and debug?

Comment: What version of VS do you use? You should not have issues debugging it, you can set break point and it will be hit. Are you using F11(step into) when debugging?

Comment: I believe I was very tired last night. so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern works:

```
private void ReSetScreen()
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(ReSetScreen);
        return;
    }

    ucCustomerNew.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    ucCustomerResults.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;           
}
```

If your method takes arguments, pass a lambda to `BeginInvoke` rather than the method group.